# ActiveRecord transactions & thread safety

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, thread-safety, rails-activerecord

My question is about AR transactions feature. Is it thread safe?

Is it safe to use both

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do ...
```

and

```
Account.transaction do ...
```

statements?

I plan to use Puma as web server, and Sidekiq for background processing.
Is there some tricks I should know about?

Thanks!

Comment: take a look on the link http://m.onkey.org/activerecord-is-thread-safe

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh thanks! It seems like AR will use one connection per thread/request, so it should be thread safe.

Comment: Yep seems like so.. but not sure if you are using ruby 2.0 and and rails 4.. where you can do multi threading. you need to check every time.